# Magento 2 a lot spam search

Tags: magento-2.1, search, search-terms

My website got a lot of spam search like 'download', 'en result', 'cn result'. How can I block this? or how to remove from the top search terms list?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past with a M1 store and what helped there was to add

```
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
```

to the robots.txt as in general theses spam search terms came from bots.
You can also check your server logs and if they check for the robots.txt first and then do the search.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can tackle it:

Blocking the spam

- IP Blocking: Analyze your access logs and identify the IPs generating the spam searches. You can then block these IPs temporarily or permanently based on your severity assessment. Remember to whitelist important IPs like search engine crawlers to avoid unintended consequences.
- Robots.txt file: Though not foolproof, adding Disallow: /catalogsearch/?q=* to your robots.txt file can tell search engines not to index your search result pages, potentially hindering bots targeting those pages.
- Magento 2 Antispam Catalog Search Extension: Consider using a dedicated extension like "Magento 2 Antispam Catalog Search”. This offers features like blocking searches with repeated characters, setting a maximum query length, and rate limiting IPs for suspicious activity and many more.

Removing from top search terms

- Search Optimization: Optimize your product names and descriptions with relevant keywords. This will prioritize legitimate searches over generic spam terms.
- Search Query Synonyms: Magento allows setting up synonyms for search terms. You can utilize this feature to map "download" or "cn result" to actual product keywords, guiding users towards relevant products.
- Search Relevance Tuning: Magento offers configuration options like minimum query length and search weight assignment. Adjusting these settings can give less prominence to short, spammy queries.

Additional Tips

- Monitoring: Regularly monitor your access logs and search result pages for suspicious activity. This helps identify new spam patterns and adapt your blocking strategies.
- Security Updates: Ensure your Magento version and extensions are up-to-date with the latest security patches.
- CAPTCHA: Consider implementing CAPTCHAs  traps on your search forms.